# Don't want to match a char followed by another char - regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a Token for a Basenote (writing a Java MIDI player).

Basenote's regex for making it's token is `BASENOTE("[A-Ga-g]")`. Now, I have a Name Token, which has to match the pattern, "C: Beethoven". (C stands for composer). This is what my Name Token is supposed to match: `NAME("(?<=C:)[^\n\r\f]+")`. For simplicity, this means anything followed by 'C:' should be matched

The problem is, my lexer thinks the C in Name is a Basenote and it tokenizes "C: Beethoven" as follows:

```
<Basenote> C  <Name> Beethoven
```

while I just want  Beethoven. How do I fix this problem?

PS: I'm very new to regex pattern matching, so I hope whatever I wrote up there makes some sense.

Comment: Could you give us an example of the raw string and tell us what you want to get out of it.

Comment: The raw string was ("C: Beethoven") and I only wanted Beethoven. My code would give me, C and Beethoven (C as a basenote, and Beethoven as a name), because I have a field for Basenote that catches any character from A-Ga-g. I wanted to fix this problem. Sorry for being so unclear. I'm just learning things myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this instead:

```
BASENOTE("[A-Ga-g](?!:)")
```

Comment: While this does "meet the requirement", it would would still match: `BAGGAGE: Foo` or `cabbagesarenegativeenergy`.

Comment: @pst - Yes that is true. But I fail to see how that is relevant?

Comment: Well, now he goes and adds a "CA:" field for Composer Assistant. And it breaks. So .. *relevant*?

Comment: @pst - True again. And if the OP asks for that, I will answer that too. ;D

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Aust. It worked but broke another part of my code (I have something that looks like |:ab:| for another Token). So I just made a new token C, which just catches C:, and then I take care of it.